# ¿Cómo guardar imagen generada desde un canvas con php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola espero puedan orientarme, he intentado guardar una imagen en png, que se genera dibujando sobre un id=canvas, estoy usando un form para pasar con javascript la imagen generada y después a php en el mismo archivo, después de guardar la imagen pasa a otra página para indicar que se a guardado correctamente, si guarda la imagen dentro del servidor pero al abrirla me dice que esta dañada o vacía. El host trabaja con PHP **7.4**.

Si pasa la imagen o firma pero no se logra guardar correctamente.

Comparto el código usado
Gracias

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="signature_pad.js"></script>

<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }
  global $con;
  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($con,$theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}


$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {  
    
$img = $_POST['base64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = uniqid().'.png';

    //Colocar firma en el servidor
$insertGoTo = "paginaok.php";
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
echo json_encode($fileName);


var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);  

 
    
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
  $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        
 }
 header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}   

?>

<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">

<!-- Contenedor y Elemento Canvas --><br><br>
 <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; margin: 0 auto;  cursor: pointer; border: 0px; display: inline-block; color: #696763;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:center;">Firma</div><br><br>
    <div class="signature-pad--body" style="background-color: white">
      <canvas style="border: 1px dashed red; width: 500px; height: 200px;" id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
 
    <input type="hidden" name="base64" value="" id="base64">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form" /> 
          
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" id="saveandfinish" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; height: 30px; background: #1b99c4; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer; border: 0px; display: inline-block;">Guardar y Finalizar</button>
 
</form>
<script>

var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
var canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {});

function resizeCanvas() {

  var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
  canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);

  signaturePad.clear();
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit",function(e){

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var image = ctx.toDataURL(); // data:image/png....
      document.getElementById('base64').value = image;
   },false);
</script>
```